# Toggle "conversation view" in Outlook with VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

Is there any mechanism to enable/disable "conversation view" programatically in Outlook?

I see only four documented conversation-related properties: AlwaysExpandConversation, ShowConversationByDate, ShowConversationSendersAboveSubject, and ShowFullConversations. These all assume that "conversation view" is already applied.

Am I missing something in terms of a property/method to turn conversation view on and off entirely?